# Accessing a function of a React element imported from external library

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, es6-class

I have a library of React components (we'll call it MyLibrary) that is transpiled with babel, exported as an NPM package, and made available to another repo (MyProject). Within MyLibrary, I have a component TextField that makes the following function available:

```
export default class TextField extends Component {

...

    getValue() {
        return this.state.value;
    }
}
```

The `getValue` function is properly bound to `this` in the defined class, and this function is available when I call it from other components inside of MyLibrary.

However, when I am working in MyProject instead, and I have run `npm install MyLibrary` and imported TextField like so:

```
import { TextField } from 'MyLibrary';

...

render() {
    this.field = <TextField id="testField" />;
    return field;
}
```

Elsewhere in the code, when I attempt to access the exported function like so:

```
console.log('Retrieving the value of the text field:', this.field.getValue());
```

I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: field.getValue is not a function
```

Displaying the properties of the `field` variable in the console log, I see the following:

```
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props: {id: "testField", labelText: "", invalidMessage: "", placeholder: "", spellCheck: false, …}
ref: null
type: ƒ TextField(props)
_owner: FiberNode {tag: 2, key: null, type: ƒ, stateNode: AddEditForm, return: FiberNode, …}
_store: {validated: false}
_self: null
_source: null
__proto__: Object
```

It seems that `getValue` is not available as a function at all, even though it is exported as part of the TextField class. It appears that my `field` variable is recognized in the code as a Symbol type rather than as a TextField type. Is there a way to retrieve the TextField instance directly? Or is there some way I can otherwise avoid this discontinuity?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that you can access the function defined in a component within React context.

The best solution would be to have a function that sets the value inside `MyProject` and use it as a prop for your `TextField` component. Something like this:

```
// MyLibrary/TextField.js

class TextField extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: null
        };
        this.setValue = this.setValue.bind(this);
    }

    setValue (value) {
        this.setState({ value }, () => this.props.setValue(value));
    }

    ...
}

// MyProject
...

setValue(value) {
    this.setState({ value })
}

render() {
    return (
        <TextField
            setValue={this.setValue} />
    );
}
```

You can also remove `value` from the state of `TextField` as you have always access to it within the state `MyProject`, and you can always read the value from the props of `TextField` after providing `TextField` with the `value` prop read from the state of `MyProject`: `<TextField setValue={this.setValue} value={this.state.value} />`.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Can you provide any additional details on why the class method is available from within its own repo, but is not available when importing it from a library? That seems counterintuitive to the way classes are meant to work, at least in any other language.